# how to add addEventListener to generic js file loaded by files not containing object listened

Tags: javascript, php

I have a js file with multiple functions around a single domain. This file is used by multiple php files. In the js I have 2 `addEventListener` for 2 forms, but both forms are in different php files. Now if I am loading the file that does NOT have `<form id="quote">`, the js

```js
  const formQuote = document.querySelector('#quote');
  formQuote.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
```

wants to create an `addEventListener` on a NULL object. How do I prevent this (sorry, new to php, js, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if the element is null or not using an if statement.
Value `null` is a falsy value, which means in if statement it evaluates to false. You can read more about falsy values in JavaScript here:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/falsy-values-in-javascript/

```js
const formQuote = document.querySelector('#quote');

if (formQuote) {
  formQuote.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    console.log('test')
  })
}
```

Comment: stupid me, I did not try this. But this feels odd placing an if statement outside a function, class or alike.